# How can I use Relative binding to pass down IsEnabled to a child of a template?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this XAML code:

```
    <t:LinkTemplate Text="ABC" IsEnabled="{Binding IsRenEnabled}"/>
```

and this template it calls:

```
    public class LinkTemplate : Grid
    {
        public LinkTemplate()
        {
            this.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
            LinkLabel LL = new LinkLabel()
            .Bind(LinkLabel.TextProperty, nameof(Text), source: this)
            this.Children.Add(LL, 0, 0);
        }
   }
```

What I would like to do is to pass down the `IsEnabled` of `LinkTemplate` down to `LL` as the LL has an IsEnabled property.

So if IsRenEnabled is true then the IsEnabled of LL becomes true.

Can someone give me advice on how I can do this with Relative binding? For example can I add the binding in the same way that I add the one for Text at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public LinkTemplate()
{
    this.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
    Label LL = new Label();
    LL.BindingContext = this;
    LL.SetBinding(Label.IsEnabledProperty, Label.IsEnabledProperty.PropertyName);

    this.Children.Add(LL, 0, 0);
}
```

Set the BindingContext property of Label and SetBinding of IsEnabled Property. So, When you will change the IsEnbaled property of LinkTemplate then Label IsEnabled property will also change.